# Post count for custom post retutns 0

Tags: wordpress, post, count, custom-post-type

i am trying to get the number of posts (for a custom post type) by author, first I used `count_user_posts($userID , 'recipe')` then i trried the work around :

```
function nbrPostByUser( $userid, $post_type = ['recipe'] ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $where = get_posts_by_author_sql( $post_type, true, $userid );

    $count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );

    return apply_filters( 'get_usernumposts', $count, $userid );
}
```

it always returns 0 …. after debugging I think that the cause is that my custom post type is not included in the global `$wp_post_types`.

are my approaches correct ? if yes what went wrong then?

Thanks

Comment: Can you enable the WP_DEBUG and check for any error?

Comment: I just checked the count_user_posts(). It works perfectly and return the number of post. Can you verify that you have actually passed the user id.

Comment: I have WP_DEBUG enabled , no error .... did you try with a custom post type? .  because when executed with the default 'post' or 'page' post_types it works fine for me too . it it when I try to get the 'recipe' custom post type where I got the issue

Comment: Ok let me check it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any explication into why wordpress returns 0 with custom post type, so I solved my probleme by using the $wpdb good friend here is the function I am using and it is working like a charm :

```
function getNbrPostsByUser($userId, $postType){
        global $wpdb;

        $nbrPost = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 
            "
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM $wpdb->posts
                WHERE post_type = %s AND post_author = %d AND post_status = 'publish'
            ", 
            $postType,
            $userId

        ) );

        return $nbrPost;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a new get_posts for all 'recipie' post types with the user id as the desired author.

```
// Prepare the query arguments
$args = [
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'        => 'article',
    'author'           => 1,
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
];

// Get all the posts
$posts = get_posts($args);

// Return the count of all the recipies for a user:
return count($posts);
```

Comment: I taught of this solution as a plan B , I am taking in consideration performance.  get_post will retrieve the posts put them in an array then I need to count the array element. while count_user_posts will just perform a COUNT * FROM TABLE query which is much faster